# Jackson Serielize / Deserielize Date

Tags: rest, javafx, jersey, jackson

Iam a beginner to Java and Jersey Restful service, I try to use Jackson to 
serielize/deserialize a date, but I can't get it to work

the frontend is a JavaFX application with a Jersey client and I include
the following library to classpath (Jersey client and Jackson jar file)

```
cglib-2.1.88.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar
hk2-api-2.1.88.jar
hk2-locator-2.1.88.jar
hk2-utils-2.1.88.jar
jackson-annotations-2.7.2.jar
jackson-core-2.7.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.7.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.2.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.1.88.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
```

the backend is a Maven Jersey restful service archetype project

```
groupid: org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
artifactId: jersey-quickstart-webapp
```

and in the pom.xml I have add

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

on both frontend and backend I have a Student class

```
import java.util.Date;
@XmlRootElement
public class Student {
    public Student () { };
    Date regDate;
}
```

frontend code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Student student = client.target("urlpath").path(servicepath).request(APPLICATION.JSON).get(Student.class);
```

when I make a GET request I get a deserilize Student object with date

```js
Student {
    regDate: "2016-04-09 12:23AM ... // this is RIGHT "
}
```

but when I make a PUT request, on the backend I get a `Student` object with

```js
Student {
    regDate: null; // this is WRONG
}
```

Did I miss some library on the frontend or some dependency on the backend ...

Did anybody having the same problem as I have, please help .....

Comment: One thing to check is if the data being sent from the client contains the date or not, using a packet sniffer like wireshark. Alternatively, have you tried making the PUT request through a REST client such as Postman?

Comment: could you show the data (json) you send (put) to the server?